# nvidia-smi executable file not found

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I have went through 3 different issues in the [nvidia-docker repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)  about this exact problem but actually couldn't figure out what's wrong.

I'm a heavy docker user but I don't understand much of the terminology and solution used in those issues.

When I run `nvidia-smi` as sudo or not, everything works great and I get the standard output.
My nvidia-docker-plugin is up and running, and I get these messages when I run `nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`:

> nvidia-docker-plugin | 2017/11/04 09:14:18 Received mount request for volume 'nvidia_driver_387.22'
>   Blockquote
>   nvidia-docker-plugin | 2017/11/04 09:14:18 Received unmount request for volume 'nvidia_driver_387.22'

I also tried to run the `deepo` repository, can't get it to work as all my containers exit upon starting, and the `nvidia-docker run --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi` outputs the error:

> container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"nvidia-smi\": executable file not found in $PATH"
>   /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"nvidia-smi\": executable file not found in $PATH".

What am I doing wrong?

I run Fedora 26, if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved this.

Removing the volume related to `nvidia-docker-plugin` solved the issue.

For future readers, just read out the log messages on your `nvidia-docker-plugin`, look for the mount/unmount logged lines, and use the following command to remove the volume

`docker volume rm -f <volume_to_remove>` where volume_to_remove should be something like `nvidia_driver_387.22` (which matched my case)

Seems like the issue is that the mapping to the `nvidia-smi` call is made upon the volume creation and removing and reattaching the volume fixes this

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, you should install `nvidia-modprobe` package. I understand that also exists in Fedora. For some reason, this dependency isn't required either documented.